# How to pass data from parent to child in Vue2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

So I have 4 components as follow

**Card-List Component**

```
Vue.component('card-list',{

    template:`<div >
                    <card v-for="task in tasks" >{{task.month}}</card>
              </div>`,

    data(){

      return {

          tasks:[

              {description:'Get up from Bed',completed:true,month:12},
              {description:'Brush your teeth',completed:false,month:24},
              {description:'GO to POOP ',completed:false,month:36},
              {description:'Eat BreakFast',completed:true,month:12},
        ]

      }

    }
});
```

**Card Component**

```
Vue.component('card',{

    template:`
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 bx_main">
                  <div class="flip3D col-md-12 pad">
                    <back><slot></slot></back>
                    <front><slot></slot></front>
                  </div>
                </div>`,

});
```

**front Component**

```
Vue.component('front',{

    props: ['months'],
    template:`
                <div class="front"><span class="fav_main2"><span><i class="">{{months}}</i></span></span>
                  <div class="col-md-12 star_mn">
                    <div class="ico_main"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></a></div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                  </div>
              </div>`,

});
```

**back component**

```
Vue.component('back',{

    props: ['months','rates'],

    template:`
                    <div class="back">
                    <span class="fav_main2"><span><i class="">{{months}}</i></span></span>
                    <div class="col-md-12 star_mn">
                      <div class="ico_main"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></a></div>
                      <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                     <div class="back_main_cont">
                        <div class="col-md-12 back_tbl_main">
                          <div class="back_tbl">
                            Table goes here
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                          <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9 pad">
                            <div class="input-group bootstrap-touchspin">
                              <input class="commission form-control"
                              type="text" data-cardpos="0" value="0" style="display: block;"></div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 pad">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right view_btn1" data-cardpos="0" type="button"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></button>
                          </div>
                          <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  `,

});
```

I want to pass the `task.month`    value to child component

how can I do that ?

**Update1**

tried this

```
Vue.component('card-list',{

        template:`<div >
                        <card v-for="task in tasks" :months="task.months" ></card>
                  </div>`,

        data(){

          return {

              tasks:[

                  {description:'Get up from Bed',completed:true,month:12},
                  {description:'Brush your teeth',completed:false,month:24},
                  {description:'GO to POOP ',completed:false,month:36},
                  {description:'Eat BreakFast',completed:true,month:12},
            ]

          }

        }
    });
```

**error**

> [Vue warn]: Error compiling template:
>
> - invalid expression: :months="{{task.months}}"
>
> found in
>
> --->

Comment: Do you mean you want to pass it from `card-list` to `card`?

Comment: @RoyJ umm the data has to be shown in `front` componenet and `back` component actually which are a part of `card` componenet

Comment: @RoyJ I tried writting like this `<card v-for="task in tasks" months="{{task.months}}"></card>` but there is an error

Comment: try `:months="task.months"`

Comment: @RoyJ no doesn't work , am I doing something wrong ? , Does Vue allow to pass data to grandChildren ?

Comment: You pass the prop to card, and in card, you pass it to front and back.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145980/discussion-between-vikram-and-roy-j).

Comment: @RoyJ `
template:`<div > 
<card v-for="task in tasks" :months="{{task.months}}"></card> 
</div>`,
Vue.component('card',{ 

props: ['months','rates'], 
template:` 
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 bx_main"> 
<div class="flip3D col-md-12 pad"> 
<back :months="{{months}}"></back> 
<front :months="{{months}}"></front> 
</div> 
</div>`, 

});` tried this its not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare the prop in `card`, and then pass the prop in the HTML tag.

```js
Vue.component('card-list', {

  template: `<div >
                    <card v-for="task in tasks" :key="task" :months="task.month">{{task.month}}</card>
              </div>`,

  data() {

    return {

      tasks: [

        {
          description: 'Get up from Bed',
          completed: true,
          month: 12
        },
        {
          description: 'Brush your teeth',
          completed: false,
          month: 24
        },
        {
          description: 'GO to POOP ',
          completed: false,
          month: 36
        },
        {
          description: 'Eat BreakFast',
          completed: true,
          month: 12
        },
      ]

    }

  }
});

Vue.component('card', {

  template: `
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 bx_main">
                  <div class="flip3D col-md-12 pad">
                    <back :months="months"><slot></slot></back>
                    <front :months="months"><slot></slot></front>
                  </div>
                </div>`,
  props: ['months']

});

Vue.component('front', {

  props: ['months'],
  template: `
                <div class="front"><span class="fav_main2"><span><i class="">{{months}}</i></span></span>
                  <div class="col-md-12 star_mn">
                    <div class="ico_main"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></a></div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                  </div>
              </div>`,

});

Vue.component('back', {

  props: ['months', 'rates'],

  template: `
                    <div class="back">
                    <span class="fav_main2"><span><i class="">{{months}}</i></span></span>
                    <div class="col-md-12 star_mn">
                      <div class="ico_main"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></a></div>
                      <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                     <div class="back_main_cont">
                        <div class="col-md-12 back_tbl_main">
                          <div class="back_tbl">
                            Table goes here
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                          <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9 pad">
                            <div class="input-group bootstrap-touchspin">
                              <input class="commission form-control"
                              type="text" data-cardpos="0" value="0" style="display: block;"></div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 pad">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right view_btn1" data-cardpos="0" type="button"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></button>
                          </div>
                          <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  `,

});

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.3/vue.min.js"></script>
<card-list id="app">

</card-list>
```